# Glassfish error during deployment of a project

Tags: java, glassfish

Glassfish gave me the following error when trying to run a specific project.
Note: I am using:

- glassfish server 3.1.2
- Netbeans IDE 7.1.1
- windows 32-bit JDK 6

  WARNING: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError

The glassfish goes through a loop and then stops leaving the following error:

```
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 17 seconds)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Locate the server.log file on the glassfish domain directory and provide us with the error stacktrace.